# iPhone 5 is not displaying the responsive mode of the website correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created [this website](http://concordbuilders.com/), and so far I have not been able to find out why only on certain iPhone phones, the website is not displayed in its responsive mode. (it shows correctly on most iPhone phones).

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Checked the website on Android devices: it looks good
2. Check the responsive website on different browsers: it works
3. Use online iphone simulators to see how the website looks: Shows fine
4. Cleared browser cache and cookies on iPhone devices that have problem showing the responsive mode: Still no luck

Here is a screen shot of how the website homepage SHOULD look like in iphones.

[image]

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap... Why not use bootstrap features? I'd say if you move up to Bootstrap v3, your problems should be solved easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to use following media query

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

you are using max-width which is the width of the target display area where as max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area.

i hope it will help you

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me either. I tried your suggestion and other suggestions by other people on this thread, but the "faulty iphones" don't appear to take any of them into account.

Comment: well i could see the problem on android devices as well And what i think it is because of 100% height so its getting the height of the device but not the width so you can try 100% width instead of 100% height. And good approach according to me will be using min-width and max-width

Comment: Your comment about the 100% height saved my life :) I set the body height to auto on mobiles and it now works perfectly.

Comment: Farjam, I'm having the same problem now. 
It appears to show good on Android phones, but not on Iphones. 

And on simulators etc. it looks good. 
I tried setting the body to height auto,, but it doesn't work for me. Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

I would assume that your problem is not using a viewport meta tag. Mobile devices often have much higher pixel densities than a desktop display would, which can cause media queries to not be read correctly.

try adding something like this to your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: I have that exact line inside the head :) <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Ah, I apologize for not seeing that.. In that case, try ensuring that the offending device does not have 'Zoom' enabled in the accessibility settings. Changing this is often a fix for this issue, just make sure to refresh the page after making the change.

Comment: I just checked and verified that the zoom is not enabled either.

Answer (score 0):

The `meta viewport` tag is not the issue.

Several [viewport tests](http://mattkersley.com/responsive/) look as it supposed to.

Review the CSS media calls, simplify them and make sure they don't overwrite each other. 
Javascript is not the issue either. I've disabled it all.

You can also take advantage of specific media queries for iPhones:

```
<!-- iPhone 4+ -->
@media only screen and (device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* CSS3 Rules for iPhone */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me either. I tried your suggestion and other suggestions by other people on this thread, but the "faulty iphones" don't appear to take any of them into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try a width of 568 for iphone5

Answer (score 0):

```
/* iPhone 5 Retina regardless of IOS version */
@media (device-height : 568px) 
and (device-width : 320px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
/* and (orientation : todo: you can add orientation or delete this comment)*/ {
                 /*IPhone 5 only CSS here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* iPhone 5 Retina regardless of IOS version */
@media (device-height : 568px) 
and (device-width : 320px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
/* and (orientation : todo: you can add orientation or delete this comment)*/ {
                 /*IPhone 5 only CSS here*/
}
}
```